# Does WPF resent cat images? or: Why can I reference one, but not the other image from the very same folder?

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I am developing a WPF application and at some point, I am loading an image. That image is a `.png` file, residing in a folder within my Visual Studio project. The build action of that file is set to `Resource`. This particular image is not alone in that; there are several other PNGs in that very same folder, with the very same build action. On the XAML side, the `ImageSource`-Property of the `ImageBrush`-Element is bound to a `Uri`-Property of the viewmodel.

And now for the weird part; this is the line of code that sets the `Uri`-Property of my viewmodel:

```cs
ViewModel.Image = new Uri(@"/Images/RandomIcon.png", UriKind.Relative);
```

But if I change the Uri to point to the [carefully googled cat image](http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png) I chose for testing purposes, I get an exception stack in the debug console, telling me the image could not be found:

```cs
ViewModel.Image = new Uri(@"/Images/testcat.png", UriKind.Relative);
```

Again, the images reside in the same folder and their build action property is `Resource`. The only notable difference I can think of is that the other images are icons, so significantly smaller than my testcat (2.5KB vs 140KB).

The exception as shown on the debug console:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 6 : 'TargetDefaultValueConverter' converter failed to convert value '/Images/testcat.png' (type 'Uri'); fallback value will be used, if available. BindingExpression:Path=Image; DataItem='ViewModel' (HashCode=55110660); target element is 'ImageBrush' (HashCode=51947944); target property is 'ImageSource' (type 'ImageSource') IOException:'System.IO.IOException: The Resource "images/testcat.png" cannot be found.
   at MS.Internal.AppModel.ResourcePart.GetStreamCore(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackagePart.GetStream(FileMode mode, FileAccess access)
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.CachedResponse.GetResponseStream()
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.GetResponseStream()
   at System.IO.Packaging.PackWebResponse.get_ContentType()
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.SetupDecoderFromUriOrStream(Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, Guid& clsId, Boolean& isOriginalWritable, Stream& uriStream, UnmanagedMemoryStream& unmanagedMemoryStream, SafeFileHandle& safeFilehandle)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy, Boolean insertInDecoderCache)
   at System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.CreateFromUriOrStream(Uri baseUri, Uri uri, Stream stream, BitmapCreateOptions createOptions, BitmapCacheOption cacheOption, RequestCachePolicy uriCachePolicy)
   at System.Windows.Media.ImageSourceConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, Object value)
   at MS.Internal.Data.DefaultValueConverter.ConvertHelper(Object o, Type destinationType, DependencyObject targetElement, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isForward)
   at MS.Internal.Data.TargetDefaultValueConverter.Convert(Object o, Type type, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ConvertHelper(IValueConverter converter, Object value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)'
```

Which inspires my question: Does WPF resent cat images? or: Why can I reference one, but not the other image?

**EDIT:**
After having tried with a dog image, I can safely say that WPF does not discriminate against cats. On a more serious note, I was able to resolve my issues with help of the accepted answer, but I still don't know why it wouldn't work before.

Comment: @JamesBarrass The property is set to `Do not copy` - on all images.

Comment: is the test image available in the working directory as well?

Comment: @pushpraj Sorry, I do not follow. The images are at the exact same location, and there aren't any doubles (at least not under the same name). Or did I get your inquiry wrong?

Comment: you got it correct. could you post the image may we have a trial with the same. _I am sure WPF is not allergic to cats._

Comment: @pushpraj I would have done that, but I do not own the image so I am reluctant to upload it. I will see wether I can find the image via google again and link to it, one moment please.

Comment: @pushpraj [this](http://exmoorpet.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/cat.png) is the image in question.

Comment: Please show the code for your `TargetDefaultValueConverter` as that was mentioned in the error.

Comment: @Sheridan No explicit markup/code there - I believe it is the WPF *standard* converter; it's part of the framework, I didn't mess with that.

Comment: Does performing a clean on the solution affect anything?

Comment: @RhysBevilaqua sadly, no.

Comment: Damn, the only thing i could think of was things in the output dir that shouldn't have been there.

Comment: Are you certain they are both `resource` rather than `embedded resource` ?

Comment: Could it be you've got mismatched casing on the filename? IIRC resource names are case-sensitive.

Comment: @RhysBevilaqua Yes, I am. :(

Comment: @AVee No, sorry. I quadruple-checked that before posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to determine exactly what you have done wrong from the tiny bits of information that you have provided here. However, that shouldn't matter so much because displaying `Image`s in WPF is simple. My first tip would be to *not* use the `Uri` class at all and simply use `string` representations of the file paths instead.

I would also recommend that you get used to the [Pack URIs in WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx) used to reference files... take this example:

```
<Image Source="{Binding DisplayedImagePath}" />
```

...

```
public string DisplayedImagePath
{
    get { return @"C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg"; }
}
```

Although (as you appear to have done) you really should add your images to a folder named `Images` in the root of your project and set their *Build Action* to *Resource* in the *Properties Window* in Visual Studio... you could then access them using this format:

```
public string DisplayedImagePath
{
    get { return "/AssemblyName;component/Images/ImageName.png"; }
}
```

In .NET 4, the above `Image.Source` values would work. However, Microsoft made some horrible changes in .NET 4.5 that broke many different things and so in .NET 4.5, you'd need to use the full `pack` path like this:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/AssemblyName;component/Images/ImageName.png">
```

Comment: I realize that I didn't provide an overabundance of information, but that's because I just don't know what could be wrong in the first place. Replacing the `Uri` fields with `string` fields and using a full `pack`-path worked, thanks a lot. This resolves my issue, but I still don't know why the URI worked for some PNGs and not for others. Anyway, cheers!